# Adding Admin Only Functionality?

Tags: privileges, mybb

I am making A http://mybb.com plugin, everything is going great so far except for one issue. I am trying to add the functionality on who can view the announcement (yes it's an announcement plugin).

How can I add it in the code if I add 
if($user_is_admin==true)
die;

All that will do is kill the whole software instead of the plugin itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($mybb->user['usergroup'] == "4")
{
    // User is admin
}
else
{
    // User is not admin
}
```

If your plugin takes any requests back from the linked pages, you need to do this check on the page handlers:

```
if ($mybb->user['usergroup'] == "4")
{
    // User is admin
    // Handle request here
}
// Don't handle request here; non-admins can get here even if they can't see the link/button that gets here
```